# how to add the constant time epoch in seconds to a field in API in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I need to add a constant time epoch of `5.30` hours to the time field in my `model` so that it have to add `5.30` hours to current time in seconds every time dynamically

```
start_time_in_seconds = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Where and how should I add can please help me?

Comment: For start - where's the time field you're trying to add it to? What've you tried so far someone can look at and point out what the correct approach would be?

Comment: start_time_in_seconds=obj.get("startTimeInSeconds"),
this is the time field which am pulling from database i have to add 5.30 hrs to this field

Comment: And that's an integer in seconds? So why not add to that 5.5hrs expressed in seconds (19800)?

Comment: can i hard code the sum of seconds like 5.30*3.600 seconds and  add to the field
start_time_in_seconds=obj.get("startTimeInSeconds")+(5.3600+0.5*3600)

Comment: Something like that yes... Looks like that'd work - give it a go

Comment: start_time_in_seconds=obj.get("startTimeInSeconds")+19800,
I have added above line..Still its not working

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to show what you're trying and what is not working... see how to create a [mcve]...

Comment: startTimeInSeconds is a integer field in my model and I'm getting the value from database . I need to add the constant time of 5.30 hrs(19800 sec) to the field. Where should i add the time in model or view and How?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood your question correctly, but assuming that you want to add 5.5 hours **every time an instance of your model is created and saved**, a possible solution would be overriding the `save` method:

```
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    start_time_in_seconds = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            # save() is being called on an already existing model.
            # we only want to trigger this on initial creation,
            # therefore skip
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            return

        # this is run on initial creation. apply your custom
        # time-modifying logic here.
        self.start_time_in_seconds += 5.5 * 60 * 60

        # and save
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

On a side note, you may want to consider using a `DateTimeField` if you're handling times, depending on your use case.